# How store multiple sizes of same image with ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have image uploads working like so

```rb
#user.rb
has_many_attached :images
```

```rb
<%= f.label :user_images %>
<%= f.file_field :user_images, multiple: true %>
```

I know how to resize images *in the view* e.g. `image_tag(user.images.first, {size: "300x300"})`

The problem with this approach is that it sends the full-size image to the view, then resizes it using CSS, so it can cause a lot of unnecessary use of the network. So I prefer to store multiple sizes when the user uploads the image, then serve the appropriate sized image as required.

How do I do this?

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html

Comment: @max thanks for the link. I read it several times, but still have no clue how to achieve what I'm after. When a user uploads an image, I want to store the original, but also create another version of the image in a specific size (e.g. so I can have the high-res original, plus the, say, 300x300 version for uniformity when displaying images in a grid). Does the article explain how to do that? If so, please make it an answer

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer on how to resize on upload from code in a youtube comment (top/pinned comment [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxx4mY4WGhY)):

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  after_create :scale_image

  def scale_image
    resized_image = MiniMagick::Image.read(image.download)
    resized_image.resize("300x300!")

    image.attach(
      io: File.open(resized_image.path),
      filename: image.filename,
      content_type: image.content_type)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Max is correct. You can define a variant and force it to be processed without being in a template:

> When you do want to actually produce the variant needed, call processed. This will check that the variant has already been processed and uploaded to the service, and, if so, just return that. Otherwise it will perform the transformations, upload the variant to the service, and return itself again.

In your callback or anywhere else:

```
user.images.first.variant(resize_to_limit: [300, 300]).processed
```